# Delete cache in iframe (3rd party website)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hi i wanted to clear cache in my iframe, but still the old content still there and the account still connect and not the new one.

Can anyone help me? Thank you

This is the code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
</head>

<div>
    <iframe id="partner-browser-iframe" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; background: #0000; border: none"
        width="1000" height="1000" src="url" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>


<script>
    var myFrame = document.querySelector('iframe');

    var myButton = document.querySelector('button');

    myButton.onclick = function (evt) {
        myFrame.contentWindow.location.reload(true);

    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Content within the iframe is isolated from the parent page.

Comment: what if i wanted to access this in my iframe "https://poocoin.app/" i tried connect wallet to new account but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Simple JS way. Reloads Pages without cache.

```
<body>
<button onclick=location.reload('true')>Reload once</button>
</body>
```

PS: First you can try to run `location.reload(true)` in your browser's console.

Comment: where will i put this?

Comment: put me in infinite loading, not sure why :(

Comment: Sorry. You can take this in your <body>-tag. When you click the button, the page will reload.

Comment: i attach image but the content is not same the address

Comment: Ok, is the path to the image correct, because location.reload(true) should only reload your page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: yes it reload but the cache in my iframe not deleting

Comment: Ok, ary. But if you want to clear y o u r cache, then you can open the inspector, choose network , click disable cache, click the trash icon and click load.